# Revert to a specific commit on Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, reset, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm fairely new to `git`.

While working on a project on `Gitlab`, I made some changes in the `development` branch(green colored branch) instead of checking out a new branch from the `development`, making changes in the new branch and then merging it back to the `development`.

Meanwhile, one of the other developers took a pull from the development branch and started working on it(`ARE-1195`). Now, I know this is going to create a lot of merge conflicts when the developer will try to merge his branch into the `development` branch.
How can I avoid this? I tried looking for a possible solution and came across two terms, `revert` and `reset` but i'm confused between these.

I want to revert my repository back to the commit where the other developer created `ARE-1195` but still keep the changes I made after that.

Posting the latest git graph snippet for reference.

[image]

Comment: Did you push your commits you made on your local `development` branch to GitLab yet? (If you aren't sure, you can run `git status` to see if you are ahead any commits.)

Comment: How can you be so certain about this? _"Now, I know this is going to create a lot of merge conflicts when the developer will try to merge his branch into the `development` branch."_ Did you edit the same files as whoever did work on the `ARE-1195` branch? Otherwise there'll be no conflicts to resolve, merging branches is all part of the game.

Comment: @TTT Yes I pushed the changes to ```development``` branch. The 2 red dots on ```development``` branch after ```ARE-1195``` was created, displays the 2 commits I made.

Comment: @AlexisMäättäVinkler No, I did not make any changes to the files the other developer is working on.

Comment: Ok, so then it should not be a problem at all when the other developer merges the ‘ARE-1195’ into ’develop’. I don't see why you need to rework your history at all. If you still want to proceed I suggest checking this post: [reset vs revert vs restore](https://blog.git-init.com/how-to-undo-changes-in-git-using-reset-revert-and-restore/)

Comment: @pratik97179 if you already pushed your commits on `development`, then had you created a new branch and merged that back into `development` instead, you might end up in the exact same state you are in now, with the possible exception of a new merge commit on `development` when you merged the branch in, if you wanted to have one or you use a MR with a strategy that creates one. So, you might not need to do anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried looking for a possible solution and came across two terms, `revert` and `reset` but I'm confused between these.

Your confusion is appropriate.  Git's author (Linus Torvalds) unfortunately chose the wrong verb for at least one of these two actions: the one called *revert* should probably have been called *backout* (as it is in Mercurial).

To make sense of both, though, we should start with what a commit is and does for you.  The image you included—which I will transform here into a new, different image—shows some of this:

```
       B--C--D--E   <-- ARE-1195
      /
...--A-----F----G   <-- development-ui-...
```

Each uppercase letter here, `A` through `G`, stands in for a commit, just as each colored dot in the original image stands in for a commit.  In my drawing, the newer commits are towards the *right*, while in the original image, the newer commits are towards the *top*.  So the drawings are different but they show the same thing:

- The *most recent* or *newest* `ARE-1195` commit is commit `E`.
- The *most recent* / *newest* `development-ui` commit is commit `G`.

Every commit, in Git, has a unique number, but this number is huge—something between 1 and 1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542975, right now, with future versions of Git going even higher—and seems entirely random (though it's not).  It's normally expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) and often abbreviated, e.g., as `a123456` for instance.

This number—the unique number for this one particular commit—*is* the commit, in an important sense: no other commit, anywhere, in any Git repository anywhere in the universe, can *ever* use that same number, unless it's literally the same commit.  So two Git repositories can, at any time, meet up and just compare their numbers (which, despite being huge, are much smaller than the commits themselves).  If repository **R** has some number that repository **S** lacks, **R** can transfer the commit *to* **S** and now they both have it.

What's *in* each commit is:

- A full snapshot of every file.  These files are compressed and, importantly, *de-duplicated*, so that if you make a new commit that mostly re-uses most of the files from an old commit, the new copies literally take no space.  But they're still logically *copies* of the files, so that each commit has a full copy of every file.
- Some *metadata*, or information *about* this particular commit.  The metadata include the name of the person who made the commit, and the date-and-time at which they made it, for instance.  Git stuffs into this metadata a *list of commit hash IDs*, which is usually exactly one entry long.  This one-entry list gives the *commit number* of the *parent* commit for this particular commit.

So, in our drawing above, commit `G` lists the number of commit `F` in its metadata.  This means that as long as Git can find `G`, it can find `F`.  Commit `F`, being a commit, has snapshot and metadata, and its metadata list the hash ID of commit `A` as *its* parent, so Git can move backwards from `F` to `A`.  `A` has metadata too, which lists some previous commit (not shown here); this repeats on and on, and the commits we find as we traverse this list backwards, one commit at a time, *is* the history in the repository.  Eventually we get to the very first commit ever, which can't list the hash ID of any previous commit, so its list is *empty*, and that's where we stop going backwards.

Meanwhile, as long as Git can find commit `E`, it can use this to find `D`, which finds `C`, which finds `B`, which finds `A`, which finds whatever comes before `A`, and so on.  So that's the history as seen from `ARE-1195`.

Note that there's no way to go *forwards*.  If we're at commit `A`, we can work backwards to the start of history, but we can't go *forwards* to `B` or `F`, because commit `A` does not know their commit hash IDs.  To make the magical numbering system work, Git *must not* ever change *any part* of any commit, so it's not possible to *add* forward links to future commits—and the hash ID of any future commit depends exquisitely on every bit of data that goes *into* that future commit, including the exact time at which someone makes it, so we have no idea what a future commit's hash ID will be.

This is why history always works backwards, and it's also the key to `git reset`.

#### Using `git reset` to discard commits

The `git reset` command is big and complicated.  It has a number of different jobs it can do.  We'll ignore most of them and concentrate just on the one job that's interesting to you right here and now.

We noted above that Git *needs* to find commit `G` in order to find commit `F`.  Git *needs* to find commit `E` in order to find commit `D`, which it needs in order to find `C`, and so on.  (Either `F` *or* `B` suffices to find `A`, though.)  So how does Git find the random-looking number that designates the *most recent* `ARE-1195` commit?

The answer is that the *name `ARE-1195` itself holds the commit hash ID*.  This is what a branch name does for you and Git: it holds a commit hash ID.  (In fact, all of Git's *references* work like this.  References or refs include branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and many other names.  *Branch* names are a bit special in that `.git/config` often holds more information on them, but we'll ignore that for this answer.)

The `git reset` command can *move a branch name*.  Technically, it will move the *current* branch name; if we want to move some branch name that's not-current, we must use `git branch -f`, or *switch to* the branch so that it *is* the current branch.  It also does more than *just* move the branch name, but again we're ignoring all the extra stuff it does for now.

Suppose we were to move the name `ARE-1195` so that it found commit `C` instead of commit `E`.  That is, what if we made the graph look like this:

```
            D--E   ???
           /
       B--C   <-- ARE-1195
      /
...--A-----F----G   <-- development-ui
```

Git would now *find* commit `C` first, then work backwards to `B`, and then to `A`.  It's as though commits `D` and `E` just stopped existing.  They didn't—if you memorized their raw hash IDs, or wrote them down on paper, or something, you'd still be able to find these two commits (and in fact you need only save `E`'s hash ID since `E` lets you find `D`)—but they *seem* to be gone.

Now, `git reset`, when used in the mode where it moves a branch name, also does two more things—or rather, *optionally* does two more things:

1. First, `git reset` moves the branch name.
2. Then, unless you used `--soft` to make it stop after step 1, `git reset` resets Git's *index*.
3. Then, if you used `--hard`—but not if you used `--soft` or `--mixed`, which stop at steps 1 or 2 respectively—it resets your *working tree*.

We haven't explained Git's index and your working tree here (and won't for space reasons) but when you're *removing* commits like this, you generally want `git reset --hard`: you want commits `D` and `E` to be totally gone forever, or at least seem that way, so you want to get rid of their effect on Git's index and your working tree, which means using `git reset --hard`.

That's what `git reset --hard` will do for you: make it look like those commits are *gone*.  **There's one big flaw here though.**  If you had your Git connect to some other Git software earlier, and had your Git *send* commits `D` and `E` *to* that other Git, that other Git repository now has those two commits.  Git is built to *add* commits, not to remove them: this `git reset --hard` trick requires a fair bit of by-hand work, but normal everyday usage of Git will *automatically add* new commits without a lot of by-hand work.  So if you've used `git push` to *send* your new commits *to* someone else, they can easily come back to you, as though the someone-else had made them.<sup>1</sup>

*If you have never sent these commits anywhere else*, using `git reset` can make them *seem* to vanish from *your* repository.  Nobody else has them yet and your Git won't hand them over to other Git repositories, because your Git doesn't *see* them any more.  So this is a safe way to get rid of commits, *if* you have not used `git push` to send them off.

---

<sup>1</sup>Although Git records author and committer names in the commit metadata, Git doesn't *look at those* while greedily adding new commits to your repository.  It just says *oooh shiny new commit, must add it* and adds it.

---

#### `git revert` *backs out* a commit

Let's go back to this drawing yet again:

```
       B--C--D--E   <-- ARE-1195
      /
...--A-----F----G   <-- development-ui
```

Let's suppose further that something *in* commit `D` is bad, but that commits `D` and `E` have escaped and are out in other Git repositories now.  You could use `git reset` to discard `D` and `E` entirely, but they'll come back and re-infect your repository, like some kind of nasty virus.  Besides, you *like* commit `E`: it's all good!  What you'd like to do is *back out* the effect of commit `D`.

Running `git switch ARE-1195` first (if needed), then:

```
git revert d789012
```

(if that's `D`'s hash ID)

or:

```
git revert HEAD~1
```

(`~1` because we want Git to count back `1` first-and-only-parent link) or similar tells Git: *Figure out what changed in `D`, and undo that change.  Make a new commit whose message is `revert <hash-of-D>`.*  The end result is:

```
       B--C--D--E--∇   <-- ARE-1195
      /
...--A-----F----G   <-- development-ui
```

where new commit `∇` *backs out* the changes made in `D`.

Because Git repositories everywhere are greedy for *new* commits, they will be happy to add this one on, *undoing the effect of the one commit*.  This won't undo the effect of commit `E`; if you want that you must revert *both* commits:

```
       B--C--D--E--∃--∇   <-- ARE-1195
      /
...--A-----F----G   <-- development-ui
```

It's generally wise to revert commits in reverse order: undoing `E` with `∃` gets you files that look exactly like they did after `D` happened, so that undoing `D` with `∇` has no merge conflicts and gets you files that look exactly like they did after `C` happened.

Reverting *all* the commits in a series backs out all the changes in that series.  The `git revert` command is smart enough to do this in reverse order by itself, so that you simply list all the commits to revert.  For instance, to revert both `D` and `E` you might run:

```
git revert c00795f..HEAD    # if that's the hash ID of commit `C`
```

or:

```
git revert HEAD~2..HEAD
```

will back out both `E` and `D`.  Note that when we use the two-dot `<hash1>..<hash2>` form like this, we give as *`hash`* the commit hash ID *before* the first commit we care about.  This—along with the idea that we can use *either* a hash ID *or* a name like `HEAD` or `ARE-1195`, or even the suffix trick like `HEAD~2` or `ARE-1195~2`, wherever Git needs a hash ID—is basic how-to-work-with-Git knowledge that you should carry around in your head.  If you need to brush up on it, though, see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which is worth multiple readings as it is just packed with good stuff.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for this detailed explanation, pointing out the differences betweeen ```git revert``` and ```git reset``` so well. 
From what I understood, I concluded that I should use ```git reset A```. All the changes that I made after commit ```A``` were marked as un-staged changes. Technically it means that my ```HEAD``` now is on commit ```A```. Now at this point, if the other developer tries to merge his branch back to ```development-ui```, is he going to face any merge conflicts?

Comment: Secondly, if the changes are now marked as un-staged, how should I commit it back to the ```development``` branch ensuring that this issue doesn't rise again while i'm at it.

Comment: Using `git reset <hash>` means you're using `git reset --mixed <hash>` (`--mixed` is the default), so Git is copying the files from the specified commit into its staging area. The files you have from the latest checkout remain in your working-tree. You are (as always) free to modify those files however you like at this time. If you wanted to throw out the unstaged changes entirely, you could run `git reset --hard` now, or you could have run `git reset --hard A` earlier. Getting into these details properly takes a lot of space though.

Comment: If you want to *keep* the files, you would just commit them—perhaps on a *new* branch.  For instance you could run `git branch newbranch; git switch newbranch; git add` ... (insert names of files to add or use `git add .` here) and then `git commit` to make a new commit on the new branch `newbranch`. This branch will extend outward from commit `A` but you can now rebase it on `development-ui`.

Comment: Note that this would make a *single commit* (which you can then rebase). Should you wish to keep each individual commit, you would want to cherry-pick each commit to a new branch *before* using `git reset`.

Answer (score 2):

> OP: I tried looking for a possible solution and came across two terms, **revert** and **reset** but i'm confused between these.

#### The difference between *reset* and *revert*

Below is a general case illustration of the difference between ***reset*** and ***revert***, and when to use what.

In short, ***reset*** is used to move the tip of a branch to a pre-exiting commit (generally back in time, but not always). ***revert*** on the other hand creates a new commit that reverts the changes made by another commit (in essence it's a reversed *cherry-pick*).

[image: The difference between reset and revert]

Consider the illustration above, with a common start case on the left hand side and the two options side-by-side on the right. Pay attention to the *master* branch in this case, as it is what's being modified with the two commands.

**Source:** Above excerpt is taken from this full length post on the subject: [How to Undo Changes in Git (reset vs revert vs restore)](https://blog.git-init.com/how-to-undo-changes-in-git-using-reset-revert-and-restore/)